# VBA Call Module - Abort process if a module fails

Tags: vba, error-handling, module, call

I have a problem with VBA modules.

My code looks like this:

```
Sub MainFunction()
    Call Module1
    Call Module2
    Call Module3
End Sub
```

If Module2 fails, Module3 should no longer be executed. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The call statement is no longer necessary so you can delete it.  Your 'Module1' and 'Module 2' should be transformed into functions that return a true or false boolean value depending if they fail or not.  Then you can test and exit the main sub if a module fails. e.g. 'If Not Module2 then Exit Sub'

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I transformed it. Working fine now.